# mod_rewrite to redirect if bad file location used

Tags: mod-rewrite

What I am wanting to do is have a redirect if the wrong url is entered. If it was supposed to be `www.something.com/test` but they put `/tet` I would like it to redirect to a page that displays what was incorrect after the slash. So in this case `tet`.

I found some stuff online and this originally redirected, but I cannot figure out how to place everything after a query string to use later

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ /test/test/?c=%1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some tweaking

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/test?$1 [L]
```